# prevent the login page to appear after successful login

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I have two activities one with a login screen and the other is the app home screen, what I want is: after successful login, it quickly start a new activity and login page doesn't appear on return back from login.

Comment: What you have tried? Have you heard the word _Intent_?

Comment: I created  a new intent to move me to the next activity,  the problem is I don't want the user to go back to the login activity after pressing the back button, and when start the app again he will start from the home screen

Comment: Then finish that activity after calling _startActivity(intent)_

Comment: then call `finish()` after `startActivity()`

Comment: the other problem is after he quit the app and re-enter it he will start from the login screen

Comment: then store somewhere (shared preferences?) that you don't need to show login screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using Fragments instead of Activities?

You can use a navController to manage your views shown.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

For example something like this in your Activity (untested):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this@MainActivity, R.id.fragment_container)

    // Check if user is logged in
    if (UserRepository.isLoggedIn()) {
        navController.navigate(< the other fragment id >)
    } else {
        navController.navigate(< the login fragment id >)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use this, you can also do the redirection in your Application class using `startActivity(Intent(baseContext, XXActivity::class.java))` after you checked your login state. That might take some time, so you also wanna add a splash screen -> which I don't recommend, because you cannot really give feedback to the user what's happening and so on.

To prevent back navigation when the login screen was shown, you override the back button:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    // Do nothing or manually navigate / close app
}
```

I would recommend you to go with the Activity/Fragment/NavController approach.